# using react-native in vue-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, vue-native

I'm new in app dev and I wanted to start with vue native and as I saw in the documentation,vue native is not able to acces some device API's like local file,but react native can and vue is just wrapper around the React Native,
So how can I use import react native compoment and API's inside vue project?
and use expo to development

Answer (score 0):

**For example ionicons:**

In script part:

```
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default {
  components: {Ionicons},
}
```

After that you can use it in template:

```
<template>
  <view class="container">
    <ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size=92 color="green" />
  </view>
</template>
```

You can see examples here:
https://vue-native.io/docs/community-libraries-doc.html

**Another example with Expo-Speech:**

Installing package:

```
expo install expo-speech
```

Add it in script:

```
import * as Speech from 'expo-speech';

export default {
   methods: {
      sayHi: function(){
         Speech.speak('Hi');
      }
   }
}
```

In template:

```
<template>
  <view class="container">
    <button title="Say Hi" :on-press="sayHi" />
  </view>
</template>
```

Good luck!